# How to create a plot which displays dynamically using dataframes?

Tags: r

This is my data:

```
     year  disconnected_ppl
   1 2010               116
   2 2011                54
   3 2012               310
   4 2013               110
```

I want to add a new row to the existing dataframe and create a barplot.The new row should be displayed dynamically in the barplot.
New row is (year="2014" & disconnected_ppl="504")
output should be:

```
     year              disconnected_ppl
   1 2010               116
   2 2011                54
   3 2012               310
   4 2013               110
   5 2014               504
```

My graph is this, but I am not able to plot new row dynamically.

[image]

I want to display the new row that is 2014 & 504 on the barplot dynamically along with the existing graph.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "dynamic". Do you want a user to be able to switch between the two options (-> use `shiny`). Or what exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you just want two plots with 2010-2013 and 2010-2014 to have the same limits, so you can slide them along? This could be easily achieved by defining the limits:

```
df <-data.frame(matrix(c(2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,116,54,310,110,504),nrow=5,ncol=2))
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
barplot(df$X2[1:4],df$X1[1:4],ylim=c(0,500))
barplot(df$X2[1:5],df$X1[1:5],ylim=c(0,500))
```

Note this is not really dynamical. If you want to interact with your graphic have a look at [shiny](http://shiny.rstudio.com/) for an application or [markdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/) for a dynamic document.

For creating images you can just use

Adding on your comment, for creating images you can just use

```
png(file="bar1.png",width = 200, height = 300,res=72)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
barplot(df$X2[1:4],df$X1[1:4],ylim=c(0,500),col = c("blue","red","green","purple"))
dev.off()
```

You can specify the solution with widht/height inside par, res=72 defines pixel per inch ( so 1 inch is 72px in your graphic ).

Colors are just added in the col = c() argument.

See ?barplot for more information as this is very basic.

Comment: thnq u:) Hey how can we apply a colour for a specific plot for "2014 plot" & how can we increase the width of plots?

Comment: Edited more information, is this what your looking for? You should browse the help files with ?barplot etc. in your r console as those commands are very basic.